# running ubuntu 20.04 getting error when running sudo apt update

Tags: ubuntu, repository, spotify

W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D1742AD60D811D58
E: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Did you try these instructions?  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-spotify-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Answer (score 0):

## the public key given when you installed is no longer available or was entered wrong, and since updating from an "insecure" repository is disabled, you can't do so.

you need to un- and then re-add the repository for Spotify and re-add the key, as the one given isn't valid.